# Vim command 0 goes to second column instead of first one

Tags: vim

When I press `0` in Normal mode, the cursor goes to the second column and not the first one.
This is not the normal behavior stated in vim's `:help 0`.

I have tried disabling the remaps to move between wrapped lines from my config (below) and the behavior is the same.
Is there any way to change this? Maybe a package it's interfering with the regular behavior but I cannot see which one.

Here is my .vimrc config file

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start " backspace over everything in insert mode
set nocompatible               " be improved, required
filetype off                   " required

" vim-plug manager
" Plugins will be downloaded under the specified directory.
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura'
let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
set conceallevel=1
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'

Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<s-tab>'

Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'

Plug 'sainnhe/gruvbox-material'

Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'

" List ends here. Plugins become visible to Vim after this call.
call plug#end()


syntax enable
"colorscheme monokai
set number
set ts=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set wildmenu
set showmatch
set showmatch
set incsearch
set nohlsearch
set linebreak
set ttimeoutlen=0
set laststatus=2
set noshowmode
" Lets you edit another file without saving the current
set hidden

" GUI enhancements
" Set nice colors for 256 terminal
if !has('gui_running')
  set t_Co=256
endif
" Set the airline colorscheme
let g:lightline = {'colorscheme' : 'gruvbox_material'}
" Set colorscheme
set termguicolors
set background=dark
let g:gruvbox_material_background = 'medium'
colorscheme gruvbox-material

" REMAPS
" Inserting a real Tab when pressing Shift + Tab
:inoremap <S-Tab> <C-V>Tab>
" Move between wrapped lines
noremap <silent> k gk
noremap <silent> j gj
noremap <silent> 0 g0 
noremap <silent> $ g$
```

Comment: Try disabling your `.vimrc` by running `vim -u NONE`. If that changes the behavior, make a copy of your `.vimrc` and remove things until the problem goes away. BTW, there's a Stack Exchange site just for vi/vim: [vi.se].

Comment: For reference, [here is the crosspost to vi.se](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21978/1841)